# Sorry, I "have had" other plans - is this correct?

Tags: tense, usage, present-perfect

It seems to me that the "have had" here is not correct.

**Example 1**
‎‎A: "Do you want to go out this upcoming Sunday?"
B: "Sorry, I **have had** another plan for this upcoming Sunday."

However, why is this example below acceptable?

**Example 2**

> I **have had** four quizzes and five tests so far this semester.

Comment: The second example was in the past. *Finis*. The first make no sense in the past, if the speaker is declining an invitation for the *future*... because that plan, is current, now, in the present.

Comment: There is no reason to use the perfect tense when talking about a plan you have now for a day in the future. However, you could say _I have made other plans for Sunday_ because _making_ the plan happened in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The first is not correct because the plan isn't something that you *have had*, but rather it's something that you *currently* have. Right now, you have another plan.

If you *have had* a plan, it means at some unspecified time in the past, you had a plan, but now you don't, which is a strange thing to express.

The example with the quizzes and tests describes things that happened to you at some time in the past, but aren't happening now.